# Laravel: set checkboxes as default set

Tags: php, laravel

I have one really simple question.  I have a form with three groups of dynamically generated check boxes. Let's say one of these groups of check boxes needs to have all check boxes as default set. 
This is not a problem, the problem comes when I submit the form and I need to have the state of the checkbox.

Here is the HTML code I generate:

```
@for($i=0;$i<24;++$i)
    {!! Form::checkbox('check_hour[]', $i, $check_hour[$i], ['class' => 'check_hour']) !!} {{($i+1)}}h
@endfor
```

and here is the code in the Controller:

```
for($i=0;$i<24;++$i) $check_hour[$i] = (isset(Input::get('check_hour')[$i])) ? true : false;
```

In this situation I have no problem to save the checkbox state, but I need all check boxes to bet set as default.

Comment: i know that page, but does not help me :(

Comment: Could be something in the isset not returning true.  Try doing: for($i=0;$i<24;++$i) $check_hour[$i] = true;  as a test to see if it checks the boxes by default.  Then you know it is your condition failing.

Comment: I don't think I understand the issue, could you update the question to explain a little bit more?

Comment: Can you post 1). the generated HTML (AKA not the Laravel logic) and 2). the contents of `var_dump(Input::get('check_hour'));`. This will greatly help me debug!

Comment: Do you wont to set checkbox by default ? What do you mean,maybe unchckуd ?Thats why set third param false 
 {!! Form::checkbox('check_hour[]', $i, false, ['class' => 'check_hour']) !!} {{($i+1)}}h

http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca/

Form::checkbox('name', 'value', true, array('class' => 'name'));